# Relationship between R2 and correlation coefficient

Tags: regression

in simple linear regression

R-squared is equal to the squared correlation coefficient between the actual y and the predicted y (i.e.  hat )

how to prove this relationship?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual way of interpreting the coefficient of determination R^{2} is to see it as the percentage of the variation of the dependent variable y (Var(y)) can be explained by our model.

For the proof we have to know the following (taken from OLS theory and general statistics):

[image: Basic]

[image: Proof for the relationship between R2 and correlation coefficient]

I hope this answer clears your doubt.

Comment: +1. Welcome to our site, Dinesh.  You would likely find it easier to write mathematical expressions (and we would find them easier to read) using the built-in $\TeX$ markup: just enclose them between dollar signs \$.  [Further help is available.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: @Dinesh, can you please explain why Cov(y_hat, e)=0 ?

Comment: if I have understood this correctly then e is the error or noise term added to y_hat and since e is a constant, the mean e_mean = e and putting this into covariance formula e-e_mean part will be 0 hence Cov(y_hat,e) = 0

Comment: Rather than e being a constant, I think the idea is that we assume that the errors are not correlated with the prediction, hence Cov(y_hat, e) = 0. Please correct me if i'm wrong.